# OpenGL on Fedora 15

Tags: opengl, glut, fedora, freeglut

I am trying to program in OpenGL.

so wrote a test program call t_gl1.cpp

I built it successfully with

$ g++ t_gl1.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU -o t_gl1

No any error.

However, if I try to run it, I got

freeglut (./t_gl1):  ERROR:  Internal error  in function fgOpenWindow
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  4 (X_DestroyWindow)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  26
  Current serial number in output stream:  29

Does any one know what is going on?

Here is the code, tested on Windows and Mac, no problem. But can't get it run on Fedora nor Ubuntu

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

//Called when a key is pressed
void handleKeypress(unsigned char key, //The key that was pressed
                int x, int y) {    //The current mouse coordinates
    switch (key) {
        case 27: //Escape key
            exit(0); //Exit the program
    }
}

//Initializes 3D rendering
void initRendering() {
    //Makes 3D drawing work when something is in front of something else
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL); //NEW OF THIS
    glClearColor(0.7f,0.9f,1.0f,1.0f); //background, last number to be 1.0f
}

//Called when the window is resized
void handleResize(int w, int h) {
    //Tell OpenGL how to convert from coordinates to pixel values
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //Switch to setting the camera perspective

    //Set the camera perspective
    glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the camera
    gluPerspective(45.0,                  //The camera angle
                   (double)w / (double)h, //The width-to-height ratio
                   1.0,                   //The near z clipping coordinate
                   200.0);                //The far z clipping coordinate
}

float _angle=30.0f; //kinda global variable


//Draws the 3D scene
void drawScene() {
    //Clear information from last draw
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); //Switch to the drawing perspective
    glLoadIdentity(); //Reset the drawing perspective

    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);


    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(_angle, 0.0f, 1.0f , 0.0f);

    glColor3f(0.5f,0.0f,0.8f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates

    //Trapezoid

    glVertex3f(-0.7f, -1.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.7f, -1.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.4f, -0.5f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-0.4f, -0.5f, 0.0f);

    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates
    glPopMatrix();



    glPushMatrix(); //push
    glRotatef(_angle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //Begin triangle coordinates Begin Pentagon
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    //Pentagon
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -0.0f);

    glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -0.0f);

    glVertex3f(0.5f, 1.0f, -0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.5f, 1.0f, -0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.5f, -0.0f);

    glEnd(); //end Pentagon
    glPopMatrix(); //pop

    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(_angle, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    //Triangle
    glVertex3f(-0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.5f, -0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.5f, 0.5f, -0.0f);

    glEnd(); //End triangle coordinates
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers(); //Send the 3D scene to the screen
}

void update(int value)
{
    _angle+=2.0f;
    if(_angle>360)
        _angle-=360;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(25,update,0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Initialize GLUT
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400); //Set the window size

    //Create the window
    glutCreateWindow("window");
    initRendering(); //Initialize rendering

    //Set handler functions for drawing, keypresses, and window resizes
    glutDisplayFunc(drawScene); //display the "drwwScene" most important part, others are settings
    glutKeyboardFunc(handleKeypress);
    glutReshapeFunc(handleResize);

    glutTimerFunc(25,update,0); //add the timer function to make animation

    glutMainLoop(); //Start the main loop.  glutMainLoop doesn't return.
    return 0; //This line is never reached
}
```

Comment: You should really be using the `glut*()` functions; they're more portable. This could be your problem.

Comment: I did. I never call this "fgOpenWindow", it must be called by the glut (freeglut)

Comment: Oh right. My bad. Can you post the code (or part of it, if it's long) that goes with this question?

Comment: What does `glxinfo | grep renderer` return?

Comment: I added the code to the original post.

Comment: glxinfo returns "Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig"

Comment: how should I fix this glx error?

Comment: Anyone know? I think this question is quite common. I searched a lot and couldn't find the answer. If someone knows, it will be great helpful to a lot of people. Thank!!!

Comment: @Alfred Zhong: This error message basically tells you, that your drivers are not installed correctly. NVidia drivers need a matching pair of Xorg/GLX driver module and Linux kernel module. If they don't match, the OpenGL driver won't load.

Answer (score 2):

I aggreed with talonmies.
It was because of the Nvidia problem. I could't find a official way to install Nvidia's developer's driver on Fedora 15. So I used rpmfusion. The driver runs and I can run CUDA. Only GLX related stuff are messed up. However, it also messed up Gnome 3.

So I switched to Arch Linux. With a much clean start, install Nvida and install Xorg according to the ArchWiki. And then install Gnome. Amazingly, OpenGL works. I guess the driver in Arch repo is not the developer's driver. Maybe just for display driver. However, CUDA works.

I am glad with that. And hopefully this will be helpful to some one else who want to run CUDA and OpenGL on Linux.

Thanks,
Alfred

Comment: Be sure to accept this answer as well, so this question no longer shows up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code. I can successfully compile and run it on a properly configured 64 bit linux system with NVIDIA release 280.13 drivers. You have a driver or X11 driver installation or configuration problem. There is no programming help required for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this question `cuda` I'm going to assume you're running NVidia hardware.

Try [installing some drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html).

Comment: Yes I am running the CUDA development driver. sudo less /proc/driver/nvidia/version, shows "NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86 Kernel Module  280.13  Wed Jul 27 16:55:43 PDT 2011"